# compare multiple columns and only replace if matching

Tags: awk

- I have two files (File 1 and File 2)
- I am trying to compare the string of Column1 and 2 of File1 with Column4 and 5 of File2. Except this match, column6 of File2 also need to match certain string, like SO or CO (because column3 and 4 of FILE1 is SO and CO respectively), then replace of column7 of FILE2 with column3 of FILE1, otherwise keep the others unchanged.
- I tried to modify and use the solution provided in the forum for a similar problem, but did not work.

  ```
  FILE1
  type  code     SO  CO other

  7757    1       6941.958        138.922 149.17
  7757    2       8666.123        198.908 225.67
  7757    4       2795.885        334.875 378.68
  7759    GT3     222.104    13.5    734.62
  7768    CT2     0       0       0
  7805    6       3796.677        75.175  79.09 

  FILE2
  "US","01073",,"7757","1","SO","10","299"
  "US","01073",,"7758","1","SO","10","299"
  "US","01073",,"7757","1","NO","10","299"
  "US","01073",,"7757","1","CO","10","299"
  "US","01073",,"7757","4","MO","10","299"
  "US","01073",,"7757","1","GO","10","299"
  "US","01073",,"7805","6","CO","10","299"

  Required output:
  "US","01073",,"7757","1","SO","6941.958","299"
  "US","01073",,"7758","1","SO","10","299"
  "US","01073",,"7757","1","NO","10","299"
  "US","01073",,"7757","1","CO","138.922","299"
  "US","01073",,"7757","4","MO","10","299"
  "US","01073",,"7757","1","GO","10","299"
  "US","01073",,"7805","6","CO","75.175","299"
  ```

  Solution I tried (for CO only) :

  ```
  tr -d '"' < FILE2 > temp  # to remove double quote
  awk 'NR==FNR{A[$1,$2]=$3;next} A[$4,$5] && $6=="CO" {$7=A[$1,$2]; print}' FS=" " OFS="," FILE1 temp > out
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping editing my code! Randomir.

Answer (score 2):

Complex **awk** solution:

```
awk 'function unquote(f){ 
         return substr(f, 2, length(f)-2) 
     }
     NR==FNR{ 
         if (NR==1){ f3=$3; f4=$4 }
         else if (NF){ a[$1,$2,f3]=$3; a[$1,$2,f4]=$4 }
         next; 
     }
     { k=unquote($4) SUBSEP unquote($5) SUBSEP unquote($6) }
     k in a{ $7=a[k] }1' file1 FS=',' OFS=',' file2
```

- `function unquote(f) { ... }` - unquotes/extracts value between double quotes (in fact - between the 1st and last characters of the string)
- `a[$1,$2,f3]=$3; a[$1,$2,f4]=$4` - grouping crucial sequences

---

The output:

```
"US","01073",,"7757","1","SO",6941.958,"299"
"US","01073",,"7758","1","SO","10","299"
"US","01073",,"7757","1","NO","10","299"
"US","01073",,"7757","1","CO",138.922,"299"
"US","01073",,"7757","4","MO","10","299"
"US","01073",,"7757","1","GO","10","299"
"US","01073",,"7805","6","CO",75.175,"299"
```

Comment: Hello RomanPerekhrest, thank you for your help. Your script looks great to me. However I keep getting same output as "file2", which means no any replace in column7 in the output. Any hint?

Comment: @kelly, a hint: make sure that you have posted the actual input samples, cause they were copied and tested. The solution works fine for the current posted samples

Comment: RomanPerekhrest ,it is my problem, your code works perfectly. I appreciate your help and time very much.

Comment: @kelly, that's ok

Comment: The solution from @RomanPerekhrest works perfectly with the test data. However there is problem with the real data in FILE2: the column2 is like"abc,45" or "abc23", which means some has comma inside of double quote, some not. Since I can not use double quote as delimiter for this problem, how to deal with that? Thank you for help.